# How to get period from last week's Monday to last week's Sunday

Tags: javascript, vue.js, date, element-plus

How to get period from last week's Monday to last week's Sunday as a date using JavaScript

I tried to find information in different sources, but did not find an answer, I hope they will help me here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming timezone is not an issue, you can make use of the `Date.prototype.setDate()` to first get an anchor to last week, then use `getDay` to know which day you are in, offset that by your anchor and you can obtain the Monday and Sunday:

```js
const today = new Date();

const oneWeekAgo = new Date(+today);
oneWeekAgo.setDate(today.getDate() - 7);
oneWeekAgo.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0); // Let's also set it to 12am to be exact

const daySinceMonday = (oneWeekAgo.getDay() - 1 + 7) % 7

const monday = new Date(+oneWeekAgo);
monday.setDate(oneWeekAgo.getDate() - daySinceMonday);

const sunday = new Date(+oneWeekAgo);
sunday.setDate(monday.getDate() + 6);

console.log(monday, sunday);
```

Answer (score 3):

First find the day of today.

```
const today = new Date();
```

Then find find what day it is.

```
const dayOfWeek = today.getDay()
```

The above will return the day of the week where Sunday = 0 and Saturday = 6.

With this go back until last Sunday by subtracting the day of the week from the day.

```
const lastSunday = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() - dayOfWeek);
```

And then to get the last monday, subtract 6 days from that date.

```
const lastMonday = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() - dayOfWeek - 6);
```

Then convert the dates to strings

```
const lastMondayStr = lastMonday.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
const lastSundayStr = lastSunday.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
```

In all it would look like this

```js
const today = new Date(); 
const dayOfWeek = today.getDay()
const lastSunday = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() - dayOfWeek);
const lastMonday = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() - dayOfWeek - 6);

const lastMondayStr = lastMonday.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
const lastSundayStr = lastSunday.toISOString().slice(0, 10); 

console.log('Period ' + lastMondayStr + ' - ' + lastSundayStr)
```

Edit: Adjusted wording to sound less smarmy after some feedback from @RobG

Comment: Good answer, but the use of "us" and "we" is really smarmy. Use direct language, e.g. instead of "First let us find…" use "First find…" and instead of "Then we'll find…" use "Then find…" and so on.

Comment: I think that's a bit subjective, but I hear what you're saying. It might also be a cultural thing as English is not my first language, and it wouldn't be seen as smarmy on my natural language. 

But it's noted, thanks for the feedback.